# How to get only required dependency from parent dependency maven pom file

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

Can I include only the required dependencies from parent pom(like we have exclude)?

I need this to achieve one scenario

1. Project A with hibernate and spring as my dependencies(there are
   many other)
2. Project B with only hibernate and spring
3. Project C with A and B as dependencies

**Problem statement** : when I run maven install in project C, hibernate and spring are again downloaded separately. This I observed because of the increase in final jar size.

As a work around I included project A as dependency in project C so that I don't need to mention hibernate and spring explicitly.

To avoid this is there a way to include only spring and hibernate from project A?

Comment: I don't understand what you are doing. In the header, you mentioned a parent POM. In the question, you instead talked about dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are guessing what's in the project C jar just based on size. Unzip the final jar (rename to .zip) and look inside to see what jars are actually being packaged to figure that out.

Jars, wars, ears are just zip files with a manifest (more or less).

Answer (score 0):

So, your all dependencies should be defined in `parent pom` and all your projects here in case A, B and C should be child projects of the parent pom.

In all child poms, you can define all dependencies needed without versions, so that they will be resolved from parent pom.

Interdependency of child projects should be defined only in case of needed. This, to get just dependencies from project A, C should not depends on A.

```
| - - A
| - - | - - pom.xml
| - - B
| - - | - - pom.xml
| - - C
| - - | - - pom.xml
| - - pom.xml (parent pom)
```

If you could get this structure as github project, then I can create a pull request with the changes.

Answer (score -1):

To Get Spring Hibernate from you need to make Child Parent relationship A(Parent) and B, C as Child.

Jar file increment mustn't be the case. POM.xml does provide reference of dependencies downloaded in .m2 repo.

For further investigation we need POM.xml